# Proliant ML150 G3 - Dual quad processors wont run together

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I have a Proliant ML150 G3  which im wanting to have two E5345 quad processors. It runs with one just fine with either processor in either socket , but not both together , it starts up but it does not post , no video just fans run. Is there a jumper for these? i have updated to the latest bios (2008)

Comment: That is a ridiculously old server and it would be irresponsible to use it for any purpose in a business environment. Vote to close.

Comment: It is to used for video rendering, not as a business server

Answer (score 1):

I'd contact your HP rep and confirm that ML150 G3 really supports two E5345 because the official list of supported CPU:s are:

Processor, One of the following depending on configuration

```
Quad-Core Intel® Xeon® processor E5335 (2.00 GHz, 1333 MHz FSB,80 W)*
Quad-Core Intel® Xeon® processor E5320 (1.86 GHz, 1066 FSB, 80W)*
Dual-Core Intel® Xeon® processor 5060 (3.2 GHz, 1066 FSB, 130W)*
Dual-Core Intel® Xeon® processor 5140 (2.33 GHz, 1333 FSB,65W)*
Dual-Core Intel® Xeon® processor 5150 (2.66 GHz, 1333 FSB, 65W)*
Quad-Core Intel® Xeon® processor E5310 (1.6 GHz, 1066 FSB, 80W)
Dual-Core Intel® Xeon® processor 5050 (3.0 GHz, 667 FSB, 130W)
Dual-Core Intel® Xeon® processor 5110 (1.6 GHz, 1066 FSB, 65W)
Dual-Core Intel® Xeon® processor 5120 (1.86 GHz, 1066 FSB, 65W)
Dual-Core Intel® Xeon® processor 5130 (2.0 GHz, 1333 FSB, 65W)
```

* Available via Configuration To Order only. Please see Configuration    Information- Factory Integrated

And:

NOTE:

```
Future upgradeable to Xeon® Series 5300 Quad-Core, or 5100 Dual-Core 
processors (Please contact your regional sales support to determine quad 
core upgradeability. Some of the earlier shipping models may not support 
this upgrade)
```

As per the [quickspecs](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04282509)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have found several examples of these servers for sale on the net which have these processors installed so they are supported , especially when it functions ok with one in either socket. I have also found the same question being asked of others with an identical configuration but no one seems to have an answer. I have also tried lesser quad pairs (e5335's) with the same result.It seems it just dosent like twin quads. (its happy with twin duals , however) but im wanting the cores and threads for the visdeo work.